# Are 6Gb/s SAS drives compatible with 3Gb/s SAS interfaces?

Tags: sas

Are SAS 3Gb/s controllers (SAS1) forward compatible with newer SAS2 drives specified at 6Gb/s? The controller I have in mind is an LSI SAS1064. I know that SAS2 controllers are backwards compatible with SAS devices. I found some information in this thread:

http://forums.seagate.com/t5/Savvio-Cheetah-and-Constellation/SAS-2-0-6GB-s-intercompatibility-with-SAS-3GB-s/td-p/35835

but not a lot at

http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/LSISAS1064.aspx

Comment: I am also looking for an answer to this question. Does anyone have experience in placing a higher-capacity SAS-2 drive into an older SAS-1 server?

Answer (score 2):

Yup, here is the info I found:
http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/6gb-sas-transition.pdf

6Gb/s SAS is designed for backward compatibility with 3Gb/s SAS and 3Gb/s SATA

Here is anandtech testing a 6gb/s drive in both 6gb and 3gb controllers:

http://www.anandtech.com/show/2866/3 (sata, but should be the same)

Comment: Unfortunately, the Dell links refers to 6G controllers and 3G disks. The anandtech article is about SATA. You mention that sata and sas "should be the same". Is that in the SAS spec? I do recall reading about some compatibility between SAS and SATA.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are, or at least could be.
10 years and still no answer here, I was searching for support of old server's card:
*HP Smart Array E200 Controller*
In original specs max disk was: *HP 300GB 3G SAS 15K 3.5" SP HDD*

later updated specs for this 3Gb/s controller is listing as supported drive beside others:
*HP 2TB 6G SAS 7.2K rpm LFF (3.5-inch) Dual Port Midline*
https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetPDF.aspx/c04140724.pdf

EDIT:
I bought these 6G drives and today they arrived. Now I can confirm from experience that 6G drives work on 3G interface.

Comment: -1: After replying to a 10 years old post, I was expecting some gerontophobics would come along and deal a downvote. When I see an unanswered question which is still valid and concerns me, you'll not scare me from answering it. ;)